# how to use apple pay with stripe in ionic 5

Tags: stripe-payments, ionic4, angular9, applepay

I have followed [apple pay](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/apple-pay)

plz, help me I haven't used stripe before. what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

That's not the right approach.

Assuming you're using Stripe Checkout, there are some conditions to fulfil before your user can pay via digital wallets such as Google or Apple Pay.

Read the docs for full info: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout#testing-apple-pay-google-pay